# How do I inject logging into my EF based partial model class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I'm using the Nuget downloads of Ninject 3.x & NLog 2.x. I've gotten ILogger working via constructor injection on my controller classes, but I don't know how to make it work within my model classes. My model is a partial class tied to a class generated by ADO.NET EntityObject Generator.

I've tried Property Injection with and without the [Inject] attribute, but it always comes back null. I'm not sure what I need to do as the controller constructor injection was all automatic.

Ultimately I think I'd like to move my Models into their own library so they can be reused, but for now I'd be happy with any answer (even specific to asp.net mvc 3 projects) to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like EF doesn't really allow IoC to be used for creating models, at least without modifying their T4 template. One suggestion I can give is to use [ObjectMaterialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized.aspx) event of your ObjectContext like this:

```
partial void OnContextCreated()
{
    ObjectMaterialized += BAEntities_ObjectMaterialized;
}

public void BAEntities_ObjectMaterialized(object sender, ObjectMaterializedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Entity is MyEntityWithLogging)
    {
        //apply initialization logic here
        ((MyEntityWithLogging)e.Entity).Logger = kernel.Get<ILogger>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Entities shouldn't have any dependencies. Therefore they should't be created by the IoC container. Rethink your design so that business logic isn't in your entities anymore.